# Grunt Uglifyjs - Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I've a grunt task that uglify JS code. When I run it I get the error:

```
Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
{ message: 'Unexpected token: name (myId)',
  filename: 'common.js',
  line: 223,
  [..]
```

the line 223 is:

```
return $.cookie('myId');
```

Can't understand what's wrong. Ideas ?

Comment: You should post more info on what the uglify does.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo Uglify is a well known library to minify JavaScript. If you didn't know that, the tag descriptions on the question ([tag:uglifyjs] and [tag:grunt-contrib-uglify]) are a good place to start.

Comment: Could you add some lines before and after line 223?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I am aware of that. I guess I wasn't clear, it would help to have more info on what files and errors uglify is having. Node isn't particularly awesome at pointing out error tracing.

Comment: There was a problem with string concatenation few lines before. Thanks everybody.